Table row is not removed using Livewire
I have a dynamic row created, and I want to remove the row but only the data from that row is removed and the input fields are not updated. I am using Livewire in this for creating the row and removing the row.
The UI of the input fields are not removed.
I have tried this but this only removed the data from the row.
This is the button code:
public function removeRow($index){
   array_splice($this->createChallanRequest['order_details'], $index, 1);
}
 


What do you mean by "only the data is removed from the row"?, also provide the appropriate .blade file too.

yes, please provide the html snippet showing the input / row in question

After unset the array we need to update the array again with the new data and update the index number as well.
unset($this->request['details'][$index]); 
$this->request['detail'] = array_values($this->request['detail'])


It looks the same as array_splice() but more verbose

I assume you are using a loop to display the rows. To let Livewire understand which rows to update in the DOM, you need to provide a unique wire:key attribute for each row:
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <div wire:key="user-{{ $user->id }}">
        User name: {{ $user->name }}
    </div>
@endforeach

In this example I have used the record id with a prefix (useful if you have multiple lists on the same page) as wire:key
If you are displaying an array and don't have a unique id in the rows, you can use the array index, but you must ensure that it doesn't get recycled (neither when you alter the rows nor when you paginate them):
@foreach ($order_details as $key => $order_detail)

    <div wire:key="prefix-{{ $key }}">
        .....
        
        <button wire:click="removeRow({{ $key }})">
           DELETE
        </button>
    
    </div>

@endforeach

So when you delete a row you can't use splice() for this purpose because it compacts the indexes. You can use a simply unset() that deletes the rows but leaves the indexes as they are:
public function removeRow($index){ 
   // I assume that  $this->createChallanRequest  is a property
   unset ($this->createChallanRequest['order_details'][$index]);
}


Yes $this->createChallanRequest is public property, but it removes the from the array and blank row remains on the front end. I use js to remove the empty fields from the front. But after save the blank row again renders.

Ok. Is my interpretation of the view correct? The blank row is still there using unset as I have showed?  For a more precise answer you have to publish the code of the view and the class

This is resolved. After unset the array we need to update the array again with the new data and update the index number as well.
unset($this->request['details'][$index]);
$this->request['detail'] = array_values($this->request['detail']);
